# Parsing csv where the last "header" is followed by a space

Tags: php, csv, parsing

I'm trying to parse csv using `str_getcsv` in the following manner however I'm running into two problems (below).

```
$url = 'http://my.events.calendar/api/csv?mycalendarquery';
$response = wp_remote_get($url);
$response_body = $response['body']; // this is a really long string
$parsed_string = str_getcsv($response_body, ',', '"');
$full_events_array = array_chunk($parsed_string, 11);
```

Problem 1 - I can't use `explode` because one of the fields in the csv is `"Description"` which contains many/lengthy prose descriptions of events. Naturally these include commas, new lines, returns, etc...

Problem 2 - This is the one I have a question about. The categories (headers?) for the csv file are `"Subject", "Date", (more things here...) "Description", "Calendar Address"`. However the last one doesn't have a comma after it. So, the entries for `"Subject"` and `"Calendar"` address are being combined like this -

```
array(11) {
  [0] =>
  string(32) "Calendar Address
  "Application Due"" // this pattern happens for every event but with a url instead.
// Yes, I know this looks wrong in the code block, but this is exactly how the data is coming in (complete with the double quotes).
```

How do I parse this so that `Calendar Address` and `Application Due` are separated?

For reference, I've also tried `str_getcsv($response_body, '"', ',');` `str_getcsv($response_body, ',', '"', '\n');` and several other combinations. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you please post a URL with a link to the test data?  Thanks.

Comment: [Test Data](http://events.uconn.edu/api/csv?calendar[]=42&start=2017-05-31&end=2017-07-01) - Thanks @RayPaseur. This is where the feed is coming from. Sorry. Updated the url. I was trying a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for posting the link.  This is a valid CSV file, even if it looks odd visually.

Comment: That is not data that should ever be transported like that; That oughta be RDF or XML or JSON. If they offer another feed, I would look at that.

Comment: I would probably try the vCal version with this [Calendar File Parser](https://github.com/controlz/CalFileParser). Don't know if it supports a vCal with multiple entries, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will read the CSV file into 251 rows of 12 elements each.

```
<?php // demo/temp_44414553.php
/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414553/parsing-csv-where-the-last-header-is-followed-by-a-space?noredirect=1#comment75830321_44414553
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// UNABLE TO ACCESS: http://events.uconn.edu/exports-2017-05-31-2017-07-01.csv
// COPY MADE HERE FROM THE DOWNLOAD LINK
$url = 'storage/exports-2017-05-31-2017-07-01.csv';
$csv = file_get_contents($url);
echo $csv;

$fpr = fopen($url, 'r');
if (!$fpr) trigger_error("Unable to open $url", E_USER_ERROR);

$kount = 0;
while (!feof($fpr))
{
    $row = fgetcsv($fpr);
    $kount++;
    if (!$row) break;
    echo PHP_EOL . count($row);
}

echo PHP_EOL . "There are $kount rows in the CSV at $url";
```